# How would you create a comma-delimited string from a pyodbc result row?

Tags: python

I have a resultset of rows stored in cursor.rows which are returned from a pyodbc.cursor.execute command. What is the fastest way to unpack this data and place it into a list of comma-seperated strings (or unpack into a custom object)?

Currently I am doing the following:

```
cursor.execute(query_str)
f = open(out_file, 'w')
for row in cursor:
    f.write(','.join([str(s) for s in row]))
    f.write('\n')
```

This takes 130ms per row, which seems like a ridiculously expensive operation. How can I speed this up?

Comment: 130ms per row seems cheap to me.  Where is the time being spent?  Database? Network?  OS? What's the timeline stated in your requirements?

Comment: The returned queries have roughly 6000 records. Writing them to a file takes about 5-6 minutes on Win XP, late model dell workstation (T5500) so it's not a processor limitation. the time is being spent in the join([str(s) for s in row]), it's calling the str function for all elements  in the record. I've also tried limiting the amount of columns returned, reducing them to about 15 from 25, this is actually slightly slower.

Comment: If fewer columns are slower, then you have to study the data types of each individual column.  All it takes is one huge BLOB column to take up all the time and make this very, very slow.  Please keep gathering data before wasting your time on "optimization".  Please **update** the question with your findings.  Please avoid commenting on your own question.  Please update it with **all** the facts.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'd use the `csv` module:

```
import csv

cursor.execute(query_str)
with open(out_file, 'w') as f:
    csv.writer(f, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE).writerows(cursor)
```

Beware that if you `csv.QUOTE_NONE` a `csv.Error` is raised if there's a comma in a data field. The sane way would be to `csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL` at least.

Comment: +1. It would also [help to set `quotechar` to an empty string](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23296450/753731)