# Export SQL Server Query Results to CSV using pymssql

Tags: python, sql-server, csv, pymssql

What is the easiest way to **export** the results of a SQL Server query to a CSV file? I have read that the `pymssql` module is the preferred way, and I'm guessing I'll need `csv` as well.

Comment: and what have you tried?

Comment: I'm new to Python, so I wasn't sure where to start. I would normally approach this by iterating over the cursor returned, joining the columns in the array with ','. I don't know if there is a more *Pythonic* way of doing it, or if there is a library with this functionality already canned for me.

Comment: pymssql appears to be a little behind the times (it's only up to Python 2.6). I'd recommend pyodbc.

Comment: Matthew, thanks...in that case I may have my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6513588/how-would-you-create-a-comma-delimited-string-from-a-pyodbc-result-row

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to do this programmatically or is this a one-off export?

If the latter, the easiest way by far is to use the SSMS export wizard. In SSMS, select the database, right-click and select Tasks->Export Data.

Comment: Programmatically, as a cron job ultimately.