# Why does this code raise csv.Error?

Tags: python, csv

I'm trying to write out CSV using Python's built-in [csv](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module.

```
import csv
import sys
writer = csv.writer(sys.stdout, delimiter="|", quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
writer.writerow(['"foo', "bar"])
```

The output I expect is:

```
"foo|bar
```

However, I get this:

```
Error: need to escape, but no escapechar set
```

The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.QUOTE_NONE) says:

> When the current delimiter occurs in output data it is preceded by the current escapechar character. If escapechar is not set, the writer will raise Error if any characters that require escaping are encountered.

Now, the delimiter ('|', the pipe character) doesn't appear anywhere in the data. Why is the CSV writer trying to escape something?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Setting `quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE` is not enough; you also need to set `quotechar` to an empty string:

```
>>> import sys
>>> import csv
>>> writer = csv.writer(sys.stdout, delimiter="|", quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, quotechar='')
>>> writer.writerow(['"foo', "bar"])
"foo|bar
```

Otherwise, `csv.writer()` will try to escape any existing `quotechar` characters, but it needs `csv.escapechar` to be set for that.

Comment: I've been facing the same issue. Even after setting quotechar to an empty string, I'm getting csv.Error

csv.writer(csvoutfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, quotechar='')

Error as:
Error: need to escape, but no escapechar set

The above solution did not fix the error. What is it that I'm missing here?

Comment: That doesn't tell me anything. Perhaps you could create a new question? Do make sure you include a [mcve] in that so we can reproduce your issue and verify potential solutions.

Comment: Thank you. I;ve posted a new question on so. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36277973/error-while-using-quote-none-to-never-quote-fields-while-writing-to-csv.