# Error while using QUOTE_NONE to never quote fields while writing to csv

Tags: python, python-2.7, export-to-csv, xlrd

I've written a simple code in python using xlrd module that reads data from xlsx file and writes it to csv. When I try to write to csv with no fields I'm getting below error:

> Error: need to escape, but no escapechar set

with reference to [question 23296356 on so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23296356/why-does-this-code-raise-csv-error), I've tried setting quotechar to empty string to fix the error.But that did not fix the issue. What I'm I missing here? Below the code snippet that I've be running:

```
import xlrd
import csv
wb=xlrd.open_workbook('testfile.xlsx')
lisT = wb.sheet_names()
lLength = len(lisT)
for i in range(0,lLength-1):   
     sh = wb.sheet_by_name(lisT[i])
     shfile = lisT[i]+".csv"
     csvoutfile = open(shfile,'wb')
     wr = csv.writer(csvoutfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, quotechar='') #facing the issue here    

     for rownum in xrange(sh.nrows):
        wr.writerow(sh.row_values(rownum))
     csvoutfile.close()
```

Comment: What data are you writing, can you share a sample?

Comment: Below is the file that I'm directly working on:

https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=3F7D0456903B9045!112&authkey=!AL76rpNJPA7cW7g&ithint=file%2cxlsx

Comment: Please put a sample *in your question*. You don't need the excel reading part, for example, to reproduce your problem. Just use `print(sh.row_values(rownum))` for the first few rows, put those in a list, and add those to your question. Do test that the rows you add to your question actually reproduce the problem. If you add expected output too you'd have a complete [mcve].

Comment: It's probably a new line character